# Fermentation Just finished up, does this look right?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, co2

This is probably my 10th batch and I've never had an issue with drinkability or infections, so i just want to make sure this is normal. I assume it's just Co2 bubbles, but i am not 100% sure. What else could it be? The Krausen falling maybe? I'd assume it's just bits of yeast and wort proteins or Co2 bubbles. Can anyone confirm this? Does it look insidious? [image]

Answer (score 3):

**looks good, nothing to worry about**

On the sides, that's just the yeast and other particles falling back in and getting hung up. I've noticed it on that style of carboy more than smooth wall styles. Also if using starsan with water with high minerals and it air drys leaving a surface that things can cling to.

Comment: cool. not sure how high the mineral content is. I use Spring water that i buy at a grocery store. I do use Starsan, but I use it correctly, so shouldn't be much of a surface left behind.

Comment: @PatrickTyler if your starsan dries and leaves a white haze, use distilled water.  The haze is harmless but can be the start of beerstone which can be a sanitaion issue. I've seen yeast rest like in your carboy even in the best of conditions. It's just the shape of the glass, those ribs are not smooth on the inside.